# How to minimize the use of FOR loop in XQuery?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am having a code as Below and i want to know is it possible to get the same result without using **FOR** loop-

```
let $doc :=  cts:search(fn:doc(), 
                cts:element-value-query(......))

let $column-values := ("one,two,three....") (: Can be n number of values :)

let $tokenized-values := fn:tokenize($column-values, ",")

let $result := for $i in $doc
               let $temp := for $j in $tokenized-values
                              return fn:concat("$i//*:",$j)

                    return <root>{xdmp:value($temp)}</root>

return <result>{$result}</result>
```

Expected Result is as below-

```
<result>
  <root>
    <one>abc</one>
    <two>456</two>
    <three>675</three>
  </root>
  <root>
    <one>dfd</one>
    <two>235</two>
    <three>765</three>
  </root>
</result>
```

I am getting the results but how can i get the same result if i want to minimize the use of **FOR** loops.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: You have only two `for .. in` expressions, why do you want to eliminate them? Does Marklogic support the `!` operator? That is for sure one way to not use `for`, so `$tokenized-values!(concat("$i//*:",.)` would rewrite your second `for $j`. But you would better first explain why you don't want to use `for` expressions.

Comment: My First 'for' will go through all the documents whichever i will get from search query and it will reduce my performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve performance you could put a range index on all the columns you want to pull and use cts:element-value-tuples in lieu of cts:search . This would pull only the elements you want and not the whole document.

For an alternate syntax of second for loop you could use this syntax :

```
for $j in $tokenized-values
                          return fn:concat("$i//*:",$j)
```

To

```
$tokenized-values ! fn:concat("$i//*:", .)
```

Although it's roughly the same in terms of performance.

Comment: Rob- Thank you :) I will try to use cts:element-value-tuples as well.

Comment: In fact with XQ31 you can write `$tokenized-values ! ("$i//*:" || .)`

Comment: MarkLogic's `1.0-ml` XQuery syntax mode supports both `!` and `||`, as well as a few other of the newer XQuery operators and features..